# Any chance for a wxWidgets badge?

Tags: feature-request, badges

I was wondering if there was a chance that a wxWidgets badge would be created. This toolkit is quite widely used for open-source projects. (Audacity, FileZilla, to name a few)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking, a badge?

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm saying. A wxWidgets badge.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but to find the link I'd have to remember which low-traffic tag badge was requested last time.

Comment: Low traffic? Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the [stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=wxwidgets&sort=stats&pagesize=30), not for a while. Tag badges are automatically awarded once someone reaches 400 (for silver) or 1000 (for gold) upvotes for non-wiki answers in that tag.

Since no one has more than 26 upvotes at the moment, it's not likely to be any time soon.

Comment: Oh, okay. I was just wondering.

Comment: There will be a badge for this around the time I get my `CKEDITOR` badge :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=ckeditor&sort=stats&pagesize=30